# Bind to the same UDP socket in NodeJS cluster on Windows?

Tags: node.js, sockets, process, udp, worker

I am trying to get a clustered UDP NodeJS application up and running, multiplatform. Here is code that functions perfectly fine on an Enterprise Linux system:

```
const cluster = require('cluster');
const dgram = require('dgram');
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster)
{
  console.log('Initializing...');

  // Fork workers.
  for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }
}
else
{
  const server = dgram.createSocket({
    type: 'udp4'
  });

  server.on('listening', () => {
    const address = server.address();
    console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} is listening on ${address.address}:${address.port}`);
  });

  server.on('message', (msg, rinfo) => {
    console.log(`${msg} received on process ${process.pid}`);
  });

  server.bind({
    port: 41234
  });
}
```

Output as expected:

```
Initializing...
Worker 11811 is listening on 0.0.0.0:41234
Worker 11817 is listening on 0.0.0.0:41234
Worker 11823 is listening on 0.0.0.0:41234
Worker 11829 is listening on 0.0.0.0:41234
Some bytes received on process 11829
Some bytes received on process 11817
Some bytes received on process 11817
Some bytes received on process 11817
Some bytes received on process 11817
Some bytes received on process 11817
Some bytes received on process 11817
Some bytes received on process 11817
Some bytes received on process 11817
Some bytes received on process 11817
Some bytes received on process 11817
Some bytes received on process 11817
Some bytes received on process 11817
Some bytes received on process 11817
Some bytes received on process 11817
Some bytes received on process 11823
Some bytes received on process 11823
Some bytes received on process 11823
Some bytes received on process 11823
Some bytes received on process 11823
```

However, the same code above does not run on Windows, throwing the error "write ENOTSUP". What I thought would fix is adding

```
reuseAddr: true
```

to the options on socket creation, but no cigar. Coupling that with the the exclusive option on bind does seem to generate workers all on the same port, but all requests seem to go to the first worker created instead of being distributed. Any help would be appreciated, since I don't really want to go down the route of managing workers on multiple ports through a nginx or some other pattern!

Comment: Have you figured this one out? NodeJS v8.4.0 is just crashing on .bind() if using the cluster module and inside a worker.

Comment: I wasn't able to find a solution. I ended up just going with a different approach for my app.